# React, css y las imagenes en el directorio public

Tags: css, reactjs

tengo un codigo en react y estoy tratando de insertar una imagen en el css desde el directotio public,(como se debe hacer) y no hay forma que compile me arroja un error de referencia...he intentado todo ../, ./, /, ../public/fondo.png y nada siempre me arroja el error:

```
 .bg {

  background-image: url("fondo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;

}
```

el error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/bg-landing.png' in '/home/rodolfo/desarrollo/Falabella/front/my-app/src'
```

alguien podría darme un ayuda? de antemano gracias....

Comment: Simplemente no puedes importar un archivo que no esté dentro de tu carpeta `src`. Normalmente las imágenes y css se colocan en una carpeta `assets` dentro de src y desde ahí se importan a tus componentes. Si colocas las imágenes en `public` no puedes importarlas, lo más que podrás hacer es "hardcodear" el source con la url completa hasta tu página. Ejemplo: `src="http://localhost:3000/imagenes/imagen1.jpg"`

Comment: Lo anterior es válido si creaste tu aplicación con `create-react-app`.

Comment: Disculpen mi ignorancia, con que comando me recomiendan que cree la app en React para que no pase esto?

Comment: Desconozco otro comando más que configurarlo tu desde 0. De cualquier manera, creo que en lugar de buscar una alternativa para usar public, deberías seguir las buenas prácticas y colocar tus imagenes y css en la carpeta assets dentro de src.

Comment: es muy amable muchismas gracias por tu tiempo, mas personas asi....